# Solve a parabola problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

So, two parabolas are given: $y^2=24x$ and $x^2=3y$ and a point $A(24,3)$. If B and O are intersect points of these two parabolas, prove that the angle ABO is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection points of the two parabolas are O$(0,0)$ and B$(6,12)$. Angle ABO is right if 
$$m_1 =-\frac{1}{m_2}$$ where $m_1= 2$ and $m_2= \frac{3-12}{24-6}=-\frac{1}{2}$. Clearly, the statement is true.

Comment: Actually, this is not my homework, but my practice for a test. I always ask a simple question which will help me understand parabolas and solve other problems easier. I have one more question: What are those forms of parabola equations called like?